# navbar remove box shadow

Tags: navigation, headers

https://peaceloveandbirth.com/
Underneath the 'Birth preparation for Mind, Body & Soul' line at the top I want to remove the grey divider line (you can especially see it when the navbar is collapsed to say phone display).
I already have this is my CSS which works for below the header area, but not for this:

```
.site-header{  
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;  
}
```

Comment: .entry-header .entry-meta::after {
    background: transparent;
}    gets rid of all the grey lines on all the pages, just needed to remove it from the first Homepage, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong element, it is `#site-navigation` that has the box shadow (and a white background, which also is a problem), so the following worked for me

```
#site-navigation {
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #fdd4ce;
}
```

A vendor prefix [should not be necessary](http://shouldiprefix.com/#box-shadow).

Answer (score 0):

**About your main question:**

You are targeting the wrong div. You need to do:

```
.main-navigation {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

**About your second question, made on the comments area:**

Try this code

```
.entry-header .entry-meta::after {
    background: transparent;
}
```

**About your third question:**

You need to get the padding out of the div:

```
.entry-header {
    padding-top:0;
 }
```

Comment: could you help with this at all..  on my Homepage, there is a grey bar that appears above 'Welcome..'  Is there anyway to get rid of it just on this page?  Thanks again

Comment: Do you still have any problem?

Comment: could you help with this at all.. on my Homepage, there is a grey bar that appears above 'Welcome..' Is there anyway to get rid of it just on this page? Thanks again

Comment: I edited my answer, see if it helps you. Edit your question to add the new info you are asking, so it will be organized

Comment: Hi thanks, I'm a newbie to this...  is there any way I can now get the 'Welcome..' words to align top with all the other headers on my other pages, as now there is a big gap at the top ...  Did you say I should be editing my Original post, instead of putting these extra queries in the Comments area?  Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer again. Yes, you should always edit your question with new infos or new questions. If the questions are too different, create new ones. It helps keep everything organized.